# how to set origin of coordinate to left & bottom uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, coordinates, uitouch

I create an app in which I use `UITouch` and I get the touch position tapping on my view.
I create one view with (height = 100px , width = 100px).

When I touch in my view from **up to down**, my touch position.y shows me these values (**start from 0 to 100**).
I want the origin of coordinates to be left & bottom corner my view (namely I when touch my view from up to down my position to be low => 100 to 0)

How do I set the origin of the coordinate to the bottom left of my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate that `y` value with `y = height - y`

Comment: I know my friend but I want change origin of coordinate programmatically!!! Can I do?

Comment: Why, how will it help you?